# Double font size on mobile Device

Tags: css, mobile

maybe that problem is simple, but I have no Idea how to solve this, and also no real Idea what I should type in to google ;)

In my CSS I have the following declaration:

```
body { font-size: 100%; }
```

No, because the new high-density devices show my fonts very small, I want that declaration to be set to something like:

```
body { font-size: 200%; }
```

What is the simplest way to do this, without creating/linking additional files or doing some serverside-processing of the user agent?

Comment: Hopefully not off-topic: Are you aware of viewports? This may be an alternative way to controlling the display, other than just making the text bigger.

Comment: Are you aware that 200% means: twice the user's preferred size?

Comment: @LeonardChallis: Thanks for the hint, but I think ViewPorts are a little oversized. I really just needed to adjust the font size.

Comment: @MrLister Oh, I didn't know that, I changed it to 12pt and 24pt in my page, but the basic question remains the same...

Comment: How wide is your page? The vieport will allow your page to have a defined width and then 'zoom' to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mobile browser detection (either server-side or client-side). You can find this at http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/. If the browser is mobile, add the class `mobile` to the body tag.

E.g. if you use the jQuery code from Detect Mobile Browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
    {
        $('body').addClass('mobile');
    }
});
```

Then, in your CSS, you can use `body.mobile {}` and `.mobile .something {}` to apply mobile specific styles.

Comment: But that'd apply to any mobile device...meaning your fonts would likely look ridiculous on an iPhone.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But the question didn't ask for differentiating between different devices. However, the same technique could be applied; just add classes for the specific browser/platform as well.

Answer (score 0):

A 'smart' high density phone will handle this automatically for you (such as ios devices with Retina displays). A not-so-smart one will not, but note that the user has become used to this already, so you may not want to adjust their fonts at all, as they may have already done so themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but my android-phone unfortunately doesn't do that, and that makes my page somewhat unusable.

Comment: @Vertigo You can try a media query with `resolution` to have your font size depend on the DPI. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution But I have really no idea how many devices support this.

Answer (score 0):

```
html {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
```